# Linq Query Giving Error

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight

I am getting this error when I use the Linq expression of

```
var emp = _testModel.Where(m => m.Date == DateTime.Now).Select(m=>m);
```

The error is

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestModel>' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
```

I have google'd and looked everywhere by I have no idea what it is talking about? It doesn't throw an exception. The only way I found out about this was stepping through the expression.

Namespaces that are imported

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Tried something like this and it still gives erros

```
string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

    var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index);
```

Comment: I've absolutely no problem with your string array, weird

Comment: What are your namespaces/class names?  Is there some clash there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a bug in the Windows phone 7 series and it was preventing me from looking into the results.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should put

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the start of your cs file.

See here for [a similar case](http://blogs.msdn.com/angelsb/archive/2007/02/23/does-not-contain-a-definition-for.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It must be a problem in part of the code you're not showing us.  This code compiles fine using .NET 3.5:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class TestModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    public void TestFunction()
    {
        IEnumerable<TestModel> _testModel = new TestModel[] { new TestModel() };
        var emp = _testModel.Where(m => m.Date == DateTime.Now).Select(m => m);

        string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
        var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be that `_testModel` is of type IEnumerable and not `IEnumerable(Of T)` the non generic `IEnumerable` does not have an extension method `Where`.

You could try

```
var emp = _testModel.OfType<T>().Where(p => p.Date == DateTime.Now);
```

where `T` should be the type of the generic enumerable you want in this case the type that you want `p` to be.

Comment: Nope, Doesnt work still. I even tried the second example I posted. Still the same error which is weird.

Comment: @user275561 I tried the second example as is and it works fine. Perhaps there is code before or after it that breaks? Have you tried the second example with no other code with it?